# I cant figure out how to make mouseOver blurbs when placing mouse over a specific area of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, mouseover

I have my code below where i have displayed an image of a map in the canvas. I want every time I mouseover a city it displays general info and an image of the town. I tried doing it by garbing the X and Y co-ordinates of mouse. However, I have no idea how I would make a pop 
up a blurb when I am over a specific city. Thankx in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function SetValues(){
            var s = 'X=' + window.event.clientX +  ' Y=' + window.event.clientY ;
            document.getElementById('divCoord').innerText = s;
        }     

    function draw(){
            var drawing = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var con = drawing.getContext("2d");
        var pic = new Image();
            pic.src="map.gif";
            pic.addEventListener("load", function(){con.drawImage(pic,10,10,drawing.width,drawing.height)},false);    
        } // end draw

    window.addEventListener("load", draw,false);  

    </script>

  </head>

<body onmousemove=SetValues()>
    <div id="divCoord"></div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1100" height="600"></canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have hard-coded positions of cities in your image? Will they change dynamically or is it always the same image and cities?

Comment: Its always the same image and cities.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use *svg* tag and inside the svg, you can use *circle* tag to define positions of circles. You can also set actions to the circles (like mouseover, etc.) to display information.

And you should keep the names of the cities and blurb explanation in an assoc. array.

Here is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfVC5/). You can look at the fiddle, it is easy to understand and implement.

HTML:

```
    <svg width="500" height="500">
        <circle id="Istanbul" cx="210.30461736313532" cy="307.8193968817877" r="26.885237584964727" class="circle"></circle>
        <circle id="Van" cx="267.4647517358868" cy="330.86253973380485" r="16.126313899958664"></circle>
    </svg>
```

JS:

```
var cities = { "Istanbul": "Welcome to Istanbul!", "Van": "Welcome to Van!"};

var blurb = $('#blurb');

$('circle').hover(
  function() { //mouseover
      blurb.css({top:$(this).offset().top - 25, left:$(this).offset().left});
      blurb.html(cities[$(this).attr('id')]);
      blurb.fadeIn('fast');
      //alert(cities[$(this).attr('id')]);
  },
  function() { //mouseout
      blurb.fadeOut('fast');
      //alert('Bye Bye');
  }
);
```

CSS:

```
.circle{fill: #a6dba0; stroke-width: 1px; stroke: #222222; opacity: 0.8;}

#blurb{
    border:1px solid gainsboro;
    background-color:Beige;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
```